# how to remove backslash from string in python

Tags: python

if I use replace function then also I get an error.

```
filename = input("copy the file path with it's name and extension and paste it here to Encrypt: ")

filename_replace = filename.replace('\ ', " ")
```

ERROR says:

```
Anomalous backslash in string: '\ '. String constant might be missing an r prefix.
```

Comment: Is that an error running the code, or just the editor suggesting you might want to fix it?

Comment: editor suggesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash as `\\`.

```
filename = input("copy the file path with it's name and extension and paste it here to Encrypt: ")
# say it's something like "c:\myfiles\test.txt"
filename_replace = filename.replace("\\"," ")
# becomes "c: myfiles test.txt"
```

You can read more about escape characters and string literals here:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Answer (score 1):

Try `filename.replace('\\', " ")`.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

In a python string, backslash is an escape character. This means it is not treated as a backslash, it has special functions (i.e. `'\n'` is a newline, and `'what\'s your name' == "what's your name"`). You can either use two backslashes (to get one, four for two, etc) or put an r before the string (this ignores all backslashes)

`r'\ ' == '\\ '`